# Minimizing Cost Functions using Iterative Least Squares

Tags: iterative-method, least-squares

I am currently trying to use iterative least squares to solve a system,
$y = Hx + v$
where $y$ is a vector of observations, $H$ is the design matrix, and $v$ is the observation error.

From my understanding, iterative least squares tries to minimize a cost $J$ where $J = \min (Hx-y)^2$.

My pseudocode for this is

```
while ||x^k-x^{k-1}||
   H = h(x^{k-1})
   r = f(x^{k-1}) - y
   dx = pinv(H)*r
   x^{k} = x^{k-1} + dx
end
```

where $H$ is the Jacobian and the output of $f(x)$ is the expected observations.

Can $r$ be called the cost of the system because it is the residual/difference between $f(x)$ at estimate $x^{k-1}$ and $y$? Should it be squared in an implementation of iterative least squares?

Comment: Since $r$ is apparently a vector, you probably meant to ask if $||r||$, the norm of the residual, can be called "the cost of the system".  As with $J$, cost is usually a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear least squares problem $\min \|Hx-y\|^2$ is equivalent to solving
$H^THx = H^Ty$, known as the normal equation. $H^T$ denotes the transpose, or adjoint matrix. 
There are many ways to solve this, depending on your problem, but the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#Conjugate_gradient_on_the_normal_equations) is a good general method.

Note that the pseudo-inverse (pinv) function you're using will calculate $(H^TH)^{-1}H^T$, so

> x=pinv(H)*y

This means your iterative method would have converged in the first iteration.
If performance is not an issue and $H$ is reasonably small, that is the easiest way to solve your problem, but for larger $H$ iterative methods will often be significantly faster. This is particularly the case if $H$ is a sparse matrix, or the matrix-vector product $Hr$ can be calculated via a fast method such as the Fourier transform.

As hardmath mentioned, $r$ is the residual vector and $J=\|r\|^2$.

Comment: As a follow-up, would iterating $(H'WH)^{-1}H'Wy$ be effectively similar since an inverse is being calculated? Would the conjugate gradient method be a good approach for sparse $H$ matrices?

Comment: Yes, you would just be solving the weighted least squares, instead of least squares. Conjugate gradient is an excellent general method when $H$ is sparse, particularly if a good preconditioner can be found.